# Trying to insert/sort a list based on 'Order' value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am creating a documentation application in which I allow people inside my business to access documentation about certain software. With this, I have a page where any admin can manage categories and users. For this, I want the admin to be able to change the order of a category in which it should be displayed on my NavigationMenu. Now, the part where it should properly order the categories based on Order inside the NavigationMenu works. But when I try to edit existing categories and their order numbers, the orders won't update accordingly, see this example:

**This is before editing existing categories, these categories are freshly added/made**
[image: New categories]

**This is after editing the categories, "React" should be Order 2, Where API would be Order 0, and Test would be Order 1**
[image: Edited categories]

As you can see, the order doesn't make sense anymore. Obviously, there shouldn't be allowed more than 1 of any order.

Now, the problem is most likely coming from this code.

*CategoryService.cs*

```cs
public async Task<List<Category>> InsertCategory(Category category)
        {
            await GetCategories();
            for (int i = 0; i < Categories.Where(c => c.Order >= category.Order).Count(); i++)
            {
                Categories[i].Order++;

                if (Categories[i].Order == category.Order)
                {
                    Categories[i].Order--;
                    break;
                }
            }

            await categoryRepository.InsertAsync(Categories);
            EventHelper.NotifyCategoryListChanged(Categories, EventArgs.Empty);
            return Categories;
        }
```

The order of the code goes like this:

*CategoryDialog.razor*

```cs
private async void SaveCategory(Category category)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category.Name))
        {
            await categoryService.SaveCategory(category);
            Snackbar.Add("Category " + category.Name + " added", Severity.Success);
            MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(category.Id));       
        }
        else
        {
            Snackbar.Add("Please enter a category name.", Severity.Warning);
        }
    }
```

The above code is called after a button press. This passes along a category with a certain order number, this number gets passed along from a simple dropdown menu.

The `SaveCategory` function looks like this:

*CategorySerice.cs*

```cs
public async Task<Category> SaveCategory(Category category)
        {
            await InsertCategory(category);

            if (categoryRepository.GetByIdAsync(category.Id) == null)
            {
                await categoryRepository.AddAsync(category);
            }
            else
            {
                await categoryRepository.SaveAsync(category);
            }

            EventHelper.NotifyCategoryListChanged(Categories, EventArgs.Empty);

            return category;
        }
```

This function calls the problematic function before actually saving/adding anything to the database. So it can take place for the newly added or edited category.

After this, an Event gets fired to notify my NavigationMenu that there have been changes made, and it should re-render to show this. This has no problems.

But I can't figure out how I would properly have the Orders be listed when I change them.
Quick reminder, this function doesn't work when editing existing categories. If I'd add a new category for example at order 2. It does properly shift everything with no problem.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I don't know if it is related but `if (categoryRepository.GetByIdAsync(category.Id) == null)` will never be true if `GetByIdAsync` is truly async. Because it will return a `Task` object no matter what. It should be `if ( await categoryRepository.GetByIdAsync(category.Id) == null)`

Comment: @Elder You're right, I've changed that. But this doesn't seem to be part of the problem sadly. Thanks for the heads-up though!

Answer (score 0):

So if user tries to make a second with say order 2, it will reduce the order number of the one that was before?

Your loop logic doesn't support that, because your loop is increasing so by the time it happens you have already passed the previous so you'll get a double 1 presumably, after.

I think you'll get where you want if your change your loop to run downwards like your pushing down, though obviously you'll have to support order below zero soon and that is not always supported

TO:

```
for (int i = Categories.Count() -1; i >-1; i--)
{
    if (Categories[i].Order <= category.Order)
    {
        Categories[i].Order = Categories[i].Order--;
    }
}
```

But for everything to make sense and not running in to this i suggest pushing the order up instead, because positive high numbers do not have the same problems in the corners so to say

Or instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Categories.Count(); i++)
{
    if(Categories[i].Order < category.Order) continue;
    Categories[i].Order = Categories[i].Order++;
}
```

Ultimately also unless your implementation is different than i imagine, you will want to actually add the new category and not all of them (excluding thew new) again

```
--FROM: await categoryRepository.InsertAsync(Categories);
--TO:
await categoryRepository.InsertAsync(category);
```

Comment: I've tried the first 2 solutions, but this resulted in the Order remaining at 0 when creating new categories. I'm not really sure what the last solution does. But if it helps "Categories" is a list inside `CategoryService.cs` This is a single source of truth, when `GetCategories` gets called, it grabs new info from the database.

Comment: @Rowin the last presumes what you want to insert in the new category and not the entire Categories list

I didn't include anything about actually saving changed, right? this was not your issue and you already master that. So of cause I also presume the order in your category parameter is already correctly set due to your comparing to it and we do not see how it is set. Did you set it already before calling SaveCategory then? as we do not manupulate the parameter category but simply add it as is the only possiblity is it was always 0?

Comment: The value from Order comes from a dropdown menu, in which U can select from 0 to the current amount of categories, or when creating one, 0 to the current amount of categories + 1. It's being passed along to SaveCategory. What I'm trying to do now, is create a "New" list. Where everything is shifted up to make place for the new category. After which it's being saved and actually added to the database. This works fine when creating new categories, but when editing the existing documents this doesn't shift up accordingly to remain in the correct order.